# How to change UITableView Cell text width in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I'm trying to change the width of the of a cell's text in the UITableview

[image]

Which is taking the width of the container as I can see

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row].User
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text=String(users[indexPath.row].Score)
   
    cell.textLabel?.bounds.width=20
```

I would like to show something like ( Truncate Tail):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think screen short seems you reached the screen width already.so there is no use to increase Label width.If you want to show the full text your textLabel you can follow any one of the below solution.

```
cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

it adjust the font size according to the Label width.

```
 cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

it makes the Label text to display as two lines.

EDIT

if you want truncate tail for the textLabel try this.

```
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I would like to wrap text by giving the max width

Comment: If you want truncate tail use this code.  cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail

Comment: Not working in the sense, Are you getting same output as above screen short ?

Comment: Yeah the same output nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using auto layout you could pin the number on the right to the right edge of the container view, place a horizontal spacer and give the name-label a lower compression resistance priority than the number label. This will make the name label as wide as possible but not so wide that it will clip into the number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, changing the frame of the textLabel in cell is NOT allowed in TableView. The width of frame for the textlabel of each cell relates to the cell, developer couldn't set it programmatically. However, I worked out a feasible solution: we may not change the frame of the textLabel, but we may change the source text alternatively. If we can truncate the source string in advance, this problem is overcome.

```
//Assign each element in the array a row in table view

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "The Cell")

    if myCell == nil {
        myCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "The Cell")
    }

    myCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

    // If the text is too long (longer than 20 char), the text will be truncated
    // The lenght of label cannot be set effectively here, so I truncate the source string alternatively
    var myString: String = sectionArray[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    if myString.characters.count > 20 {

        let myIndex = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 20)
        myString = myString.substring(to: myIndex)
        myString += "..."
    }

    myCell?.textLabel?.text = myString
    myCell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(NSDate())"

    return myCell!
}
```

With this method, the effect of changing the textLabel's frame could be achieved.